# Oracle DB query - joining two tables

Tags: database, oracle, join

I was trying to write an oracle database query

Table 1 contains

```
ID      Name   Action IP Address
11345   James  Copy   10.1.1.1
11345   James  Create 10.1.1.1
34512   Alex   Delete 10.1.1.2
```

Table 2 contains

```
ID     UserID  Name   IP Address
11345  jusb    James  10.1.1.1
34512  awaters Alex   10.1.1.2
```

Desired output

```
ID      UserID  Name   Action   IP Address
11345   jusb    James  Copy     10.1.1.1
11345   jusb    James  Create   10.1.1.1
34512   awaters Alex   Delete   10.1.1.2
```

The ID is unique in the second table but repeats in the first table. I basically want to add the UserID field to each entry in table 1.

This is what I tried so far

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Action, t2.UserID, t1.IPAddress from Table1 t1 
left outer join Table2 t2 on t1.ID =t2.ID
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Updated with what I tried so far.

Comment: and what is wrong with the output from your attempt?

Comment: Thanks. What output are you getting with that query? Assuming you've got the table and column names right, the query looks correct.

Comment: @Bacs For some reason I get the first and second row. The query seems to skip the middle entry since it was already identified in table 2

Comment: Not sure how to help. There's something else going on here. Your query should be fetching all three records, given the tables and data as you've presented them.

Answer (score 0):

1- It's better to use inner join for this case, because every record in table 1 has a id in table 2.
2- In left outer join case you can also get result with Table 1 has record that's not exists in Table 2.

Final query is like this :

```
select t1.ID, t2.UserID, t1.Name, t1.Action, t1.IPAddress from Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID =t2.ID
```

Comment: I tried an inner join but it again seems to skip the second row in the final result. The first time it encounter an ID in table 1 it checks for the same in table 2. I am not sure why but the second time the ID is encountered it does not display it.

Comment: Can you explain a little clear, or get us your query and what you want?